# Expansion of columns in a table in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way in the table, to merge selected columns into one column that sums the values ​​of them all together, and vice versa, but in a way that it can be done with the cursor (or with a particular button or creating of such a button? I mean, a tool that resembles a collapsing menu). Pivot is not an option for me.

**Example (First row belongs to Excel's bar):**

Column A originally consists of two columns (that I had the option to choose in the first place), summarizing the values ​​of each row in them.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 7 |
| 11 | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 |

Using my mouse, or at the push of a button, I can expand column A and view the columns that make it up, like this (same table as before. column A expanded to become columns A and B):

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 2 | 9 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 6 |

English is not my native language! I would be happy if you would edit the question so it could be more readable. Thanks!

Comment: This might be possible using VBA. You'd have three columns: A, B, and C. C=A+B. Clicking the button would toggle C being hidden or A and B being hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group your data.
It would take 2 mouse clicks. And you have to have one (empty) column inbetween otherwise you cant see the plus sign for expanding.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! your answer is certainly satisfying!

Comment: @ron The grouping lines can take space from your screen. One can hide and unhide it with CTRL+8 (shortcuts are sometimes different in different Excel versions)